# Importing Encoded .txt File into Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .txt file with some data from a device I use.  I am trying to upload said data into Python, to make a matrix from each of the columns/rows (3 columns x 12000ish rows).

Here's the code I am using to do this.

```
filePath = "C:/Users/SBEHJE/Desktop/after temp 2.txt"

text_file = open(filePath, "r")

lines = text_file.read()
```

When I use this code, the string is in unicode, but with some strange characters, too, like ©.  It can be seen below in bold, just to clarify

```
\x002\x000\x002\x001\x00 \x00 \x001\x009\x00:\x005\x009\x00:\x001\x009\x00\t\x00-\x00-\x00\t\x001\x00.\x000\x002\x007\x00k\x00**©**\x03\n\x00\n\x002\x006\x00/\x000\x007\x00/\x002\x000\x002\x001\x00 \x00 \x001\x009\x00
```

So, I tried to encode the string into a byte using:

```
lines = lines.encode(encoding='utf-16', errors='ignore')
```

But, when I decode it back into a string with:

```
lines = lines.decode(encoding='utf-16', errors='ignore')
```

It goes back to still having this character:  ©.  Additionally, the whole string is still in unicode.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi all, I found the solution.  In the bottom right of the text file, it may tell you how the text was encoded, (for me it was UTF-16 LE).  By using the following code, I solved my issue.  filePath = "C:/Users/SBEHJE/Desktop/after temp 2.txt"
text_file = open(filePath, "r", encoding='utf-16 LE')
lines = text_file.read()

Comment: To clarify the terminology: you initially *decoded* the file incorrectly, using UTF-8 (the default) when you should have used UTF-16. Re-encoding then decoding the resulting garbage just leaves you with the original garbage. As you discovered, the solution is to correctly decode the file using UTF-16 in the first place.